# Use main class' properties in subclass？

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, django-models

sample:

```
from django.db import models


class BaseModel(models.Model):
    CHOICES = ((0, 'nope'),
               (1, 'yep'),)
    # ...


class P(BaseModel):
    p = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1, choices=BaseModel.CHOICES)
```

It's unnecessary to inherit the `BaseModel` if I just use `BaseModel.CHOICES`.But I must inherit it because some other column.

How to let the `P` inherit the `CHOICES` property instead of using it's father's `CHOICES`?

Comment: are you try to create function return choice values and use it. like 
def get_choice():
    return ((0, 'nope'),
            (1, 'yep'),) and use like p = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1, choices=get_choice)

Comment: There's no magic thingy like `super()`, if that's what you're asking. This seems like the right way.

Comment: @giaosudau I just want to put all things in `BaseModel`, and let the subclass looks as clean as enough , do you mean I should write a `get_choice` method for every subclass?

Comment: @Sinux it outside a class just a static function or just create a constant .

Comment: @giaosudau It's not only one `CHOICES`, then I need write a method for each property in `BaseModel` ,that may be a large number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `p` is not an inherited field, so it cannot "inherit" anything from `BaseModel`. `P` (the subclass) *will* inherit `CHOICES` from `BaseModel` but at the point where field `p` is defined the `P` class doesn't yet exists (it will only exists after the end of the `class` statement body), so you cannot reference `P.CHOICES` at this point, and since the name `CHOICES` is not defined in the `P` class statement's body, you cannot reference it either. So basically your snippet is the plain simple and obvious solution.